# Chromium にAutoscriptrunner を導入したい

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chrome-extension

任意のサイトで任意のJavaScriptを自動実行させるChrome拡張 で
以下のようなものがあります。

http://qiita.com/nakajmg/items/bcbf0e5debcfa70c8d63

これをChromium で使用したいのですが、インストールはできたものの
動作しません。※アイコンをクリックしても動きません

Chromium にextensionを追加する方法 として以下の記事を参考にしましたが、
この方法でも無理でした。
https://joppot.info/2017/02/06/3371

何か方法はないものでしょうか？

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/88608

Answer (score 0):

環境：
　Win7_32bit

実現手順
①最新ソフトをダウンロードし、展開する
　https://download-chromium.appspot.com/
[chrome-win32.zip](https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/Win/496959/chrome-win32.zip)
②chrome.exe実施して、下記のURLを開いて、CHROMEに追加ボタンを押下する
　https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/ScriptAutoRunner?hl=ja
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
③拡張機能を追加ボタンを押下する
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
④追加完了のメッセージを表示すれば、追加成功！
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
⑤URL右の[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]ボタンを押下する
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
⑥[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]を押下して、JSを作ります。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
⑦完成
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]